# Repeat ground track with 1 day repetition

Tags: low-earth-orbit, ground-track

I'm struggling with a doubt regarding repeating ground tracks (RGT). I've a satellite in a LEO circular orbit with a predefined non-polar inclination (64°) and I want to determine the needed semi-major axis in order to have a repeat ground track.
I found several references in literature to compute the repeat ratio of a RGT orbit, but I'm not sure how this could be use to find the information I'm interested in.
If I compute the repeat ratio as in the formula
$$\tau = \frac{N_S}{N_D} = \frac{T_N}{T_S} = \frac{2\pi / (\omega_E-\dot{\Omega})}{2\pi / (\dot{M}-\dot{\omega})} = \frac{n + \Delta n + \dot{\omega}}{\omega_E - \dot{\Omega}}$$

how do I determine if a given sma leads to a RGT? Does this ratio need to be an integer number?

Comment: I have converted your equation to MatJax (edit may be pending), please check that I have done so correctly and consider using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in the future.

Comment: If you want an exact repetition after 1 day, how should this be possible without an integer number ratio? To keep the repeat ratio constant over time, orbit correction maneuvers might be necessary.